# Facing 404 page not found when trying to pass value in url in Codeighter

Tags: php, codeigniter, uri

I am trying to pass value in url

> http://192.168.1.136/dashboard/Projects/CodeIgniter-3.1.11/index.php/calls/call_id

And facing 404 page not found error.

I want to pass `call_id` to controller. Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

This is controller

```
  class Calls extends CI_Controller {

    // I WANT TO ACCESS call_id HERE
    function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index($abc) {

      $this->load->helper('url');
      $call =  $this->uri->segment(3);
      $data = array('call_id' => $call, 'bar' => 'world');
      $this->load->view('Pages/MyAjax.php', $data);
    }
  }
```

This is router configuration

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

This is config.php

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
$config['url_suffix'] = '';
$config['language'] = 'english';
$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';
$config['enable_hooks'] = FALSE;
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';
$config['composer_autoload'] = FALSE;
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
$config['controller_trigger'] = 'c';
$config['function_trigger'] = 'm';
$config['directory_trigger'] = 'd';
$config['allow_get_array'] = TRUE;
$config['log_threshold'] = 0;
$config['log_path'] = '';
$config['log_file_extension'] = '';
$config['log_file_permissions'] = 0644;
$config['log_date_format'] = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
$config['error_views_path'] = '';
$config['cache_path'] = '';
$config['cache_query_string'] = FALSE;
$config['encryption_key'] = '';
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
$config['cookie_prefix']    = '';
$config['cookie_domain']    = '';
$config['cookie_path']      = '/';
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;
$config['standardize_newlines'] = FALSE;
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;
$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf_test_name';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_cookie_name';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
$config['csrf_regenerate'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array();
$config['compress_output'] = FALSE;
$config['time_reference'] = 'local';
$config['rewrite_short_tags'] = FALSE;
$config['proxy_ips'] = '';
```

I want to access call_id in `controller`.

Comment: I think you wrote the construct function wrongly.

Comment: read documentation [Passing URI Segments to your methods](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html?highlight=controller#passing-uri-segments-to-your-methods)

Comment: Your code is right, but you are hitting wrong url, your url should be `http://192.168.1.136/dashboard/Projects/CodeIgniter-3.1.11/index.php/calls/index/1`  where `1` is the call_id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add parameters to `index()` like this `index($call_id = NULL)`

controller

```
  class Calls extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index($call_id = NULL) {

      // $this->load->helper('url');
      // $call =  $this->uri->segment(3);
      $data = array('call_id' => $call_id, 'bar' => 'world');
      $this->load->view('Pages/MyAjax.php', $data);
    }
  }
```

and url

> http://192.168.1.136/dashboard/Projects/CodeIgniter-3.1.11/index.php/calls/index/30

where last segment in above url `30` is call_id